# Serverless framework - schedule rate "cron" not yet supported

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, serverless-framework

I am using "serverless": "^2.43.1".

I am following official docs from:
https://www.serverless.com/examples/aws-node-scheduled-cron

but.. this does not seems to work at all..
All I get is:

```
schedule rate "cron" not yet supported!
scheduler: invalid, schedule syntax
Scheduling [my lambda name] cron: [undefined] input: undefined
```

Tried with official example:

```
functions:
  myHandler:
    handler: handler.run
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0/2 * ? * MON-FRI *)
```

Or even just to invoke it every minute:

```
functions:
  myHandler:
    handler: handler.run
    events:
      - schedule: cron(* * * * *)
```

but the error persist and lambda is not invoked both locally (serverless offline) and on AWS cloud

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

use rate format !

```
- schedule: rate(1 minute)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

1.install serverless-offline-scheduler npm package

2. And add the same plugin to your serverless.yml file

plugins:

- serverless-webpack
- serverless-offline
- serverless-offline-scheduler

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).